# How can run cmd in aws_ecs_task_definition terraform aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, ecs-taskdefinition, n8n

I need to run docker cmd in aws_ecs_task_definition I can directly run that in my local machine docker but unable to run that on task_defination

```
        docker run -it --rm \
    --name n8n \
    -p 5678:5678 \
    -e DB_TYPE=postgresdb \
    -e DB_POSTGRESDB_DATABASE=<POSTGRES_DATABASE> \
    -e DB_POSTGRESDB_HOST=<POSTGRES_HOST> \
    -e DB_POSTGRESDB_PORT=<POSTGRES_PORT> \
    -e DB_POSTGRESDB_USER=<POSTGRES_USER> \
    -e DB_POSTGRESDB_SCHEMA=<POSTGRES_SCHEMA> \
    -e DB_POSTGRESDB_PASSWORD=<POSTGRES_PASSWORD> \
    -v ~/.n8n:/home/node/.n8n \
    n8nio/n8n \
    n8n start
```

thats the cmd I need to run but can working fine locally but unable to from aws_ecs_task_definition

I tried to run that cmd from
**command** inside **container_definitions** but unable to run that

**edited**

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "task-definition" {
  family                = "${var.PROJECT_NAME}-task-definition"
  container_definitions = jsonencode([
    {
      name      = "${var.PROJECT_NAME}-task-container"
      image     = "${var.IMAGE_PATH}"
      cpu       = 10
      memory    = 512
      essential = true
      environment = [
        {name: "DB_TYPE", value: "postgresdb"},
        {name: "DB_POSTGRESDB_DATABASE", value: "${var.DB_NAME}"},
        {name: "DB_POSTGRESDB_HOST", value: "${var.DB_NAME}"},
        {name: "DB_POSTGRESDB_DATABASE", value: "${aws_db_instance.rds.address}"},
        {name: "DB_POSTGRESDB_PORT", value: "5432"},
        {name: "DB_POSTGRESDB_USER", value: "${var.DB_USERNAME}"},
        {name: "DB_POSTGRESDB_PASSWORD", value: "${var.DB_PASSWORD}"},
      ]
      
      command   = [
        "docker", "run", 
        "-it", "--rm", 
        "--name", "${var.IMAGE_PATH}",  
        "-v", "~/.n8n:/home/node/.n8n", 
        "n8nio/n8n", 
        "n8n", "start",
        "n8n", "restart"
      ]

      portMappings = [
        {
          containerPort = 5678
          hostPort      = 5678
        }
      ]
    }
  ])

  depends_on = [
    aws_db_instance.rds
  ]
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "service" {
  name            = "${var.PROJECT_NAME}-ecs-service"
  cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.ecs-cluster.id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.task-definition.arn
  desired_count   = 1
  iam_role        = aws_iam_role.ecs-service-role.arn
  depends_on      = [aws_iam_policy_attachment.ecs-service-attach]

  load_balancer {
    elb_name       = aws_elb.elb.name
    container_name = "${var.PROJECT_NAME}-task-container"
    container_port = 5678
  }

  
}
```

Comment: Sorry but what is "running command in aws_ecs_task_definition"? You mean exec to your running container which is in ECS task right?

Comment: yes, inside aws_ecs_task_definition I have container_definitions at their I try to pass this, and aws_ecs_task_definition was used by aws_ecs_service

Comment: @MarkoE in docs its says that write inside the commad attribute which I already tried, using that It gives me 503 error, for persistence of data I need to connect with db, otherwise its working for me

Comment: You have only showed the Docker command and there is no terraform code. So without that it's almost impossible to say what could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `command` in an ECS task definition doesn't take a `docker` command. It is the command that should be run inside the docker container that ECS is starting. ECS is a docker orchestration service. ECS runs the `docker` commands for you behind the scenes, you never give ECS a direct `docker` command to run.

Looking at the `docker` command you are running locally, the `command` part that is being executed inside the container is `n8n start`. So your `command` should be:

```
     command   = [
        "n8n", "start"
      ]
```

All those other `docker` command arguments, like the container name, volume mapping, environment variables, image ID, are all arguments that you have would elsewhere in the ECS task definition. It appears you have already specified all those arguments in your Task definition elsewhere, except for the volume mapping.